# JQuery preserve draggability when element is removed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm trying to move a draggable element around in the DOM, but whenever I try replaceWith() or remove() or similar functions, its draggability is lost.

Is it possible to make an element not lose its draggability when moving it around in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to not use jQuery to move the elements around, but to use the pure DOM.

That is, instead of

```
$('#elem').remove().appendTo($('#elem2'))
```

do

```
var q = $('#elem'); var el = q.get(0); el.parentNode.removeChild(el); $('#elem2').appendChild(el);
```

I don't know if it's recommended, but it works.

Comment: I know it's an old answer but if you don't mind I would like to know why using the pure DOM solve the issue? by the way you saved my day thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to create the draggable behaviour again after you move around the DOM:

```
function xyz(){
    //move your stuff
    //create the draggable again

    $(element).draggable();
}
```

Comment: Because due to how my architecture is, I can't

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to preserve draggability when you replace/remove elements in the DOM, unless you modify the jquery core (which I do not recommend.)

Doing `replaceWith()` and `remove()` for DOM elements means they are destroyed, and thus any behaviors or events associated with them are destroyed as well.

Try creating an outer `<div>` which contains the draggable behavior and instead replace the HTML within the `div` when you want to change the draggable item upon drop, etc.

Alternatively (and less elegant) you can call `draggable()` again on your elements after your do `replaceWith()` to restore the behavior you removed with `replaceWith()`.

Likewise, instead of `remove()` try `hide()` to simply make elements disappear for a while but retain their behavior.

In short: You are approaching the problem incorrectly. Change your approach.